# How do I know I've marked a message "not junk"?

Tags: email, thunderbird, spam-prevention

Thunderbird's documentation regarding the junk filter indicates that in training the filter it is important to advise Thunderbird as to what messages are *not* junk as well as what messages are.

One can press Shift+J or use the context menus to mark a message "not junk," but I have noticed that, in doing so, nothing at all in the user interface changes.  Messages I have classified as junk have the flame icon lit orange.  The icon is grey for messages that have not been classified at all, and it stays grey when I try to mark a message as "not junk."

How can I tell whether I have actually marked a message as "not junk"?

Does marking a previously unmarked message as "not junk" even do anything, or is the act of marking "not junk" only meaningful when applied to mail that has already been misclassified as junk?  (Source of this information should be indicated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Mozilla support page [Thunderbird and Junk / Spam Messages](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-junk-spam-messages) states

> **Tell Thunderbird what is NOT junk**
>
> It as just as important to tell the filter which messages are not junk.
>
> First, during the early learning stages you will want to frequently, perhaps daily, check your Junk folder for messages that have been incorrectly classified as junk by clicking on the Not junk button, or using the upper case J on your keyboard. After the first week you should also check the junk folder for messages that are incorrectly marked as junk, perhaps weekly.
>
> Secondly, very important, you will want to constantly train the filter by marking a quantity of GOOD messages as not junk, for example messages in your Inbox. You must use the keyboard upper case J, because there is no button - the "Not Junk" button appears only for messages that have already been classified as junk. Marking several messages per week will be sufficient. You can select many messages and mark them all at the same time. **Note - unfortunately nothing in the user interface indicates whether a message has already been marked as "not junk".**

Have a look in the rest of the page as well, there are some interesting tips.

Comment: Thank you!  Not sure how I missed that!  Maybe I was paying more attention to Mozillazine.. they're usually pretty thorough, but seem to have omitted that point.

Comment: @Kevin. No worries. Tbh, it's easy to be missed since it's the final sentence, not in bold or distinctive. I've missed something in documentation so many times that I cannot even remember anymore.